# Проигрывание музыки 1 раз

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите как сделать проигрывание звука на сайте только 1 раз.
Пользователь зашел - проигрался звук, но если он опять перешел с другой вкладки там где лежит скрипт то звука уже не было. HTML или JS

Comment: `javascript cookie`, если кука есть музыка не играет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью **localstorage**

```
var playedSound = localStorage.getItem('played');

if(!playedSound) {
    // тут воспроизводим звук (вставляем код воспроизведения)
    localStorage.setItem('played','true');
}
```

Используя **cookies**

```
var playedSound = readCookie('played');

if(!playedSound){
    // тут воспроизводим звук (вставляем код воспроизведения)
    createCookie('played','true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо между сессиями, сохранить данные о том, что музыка уже была проиграна, для этого вы можете или использовать [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), как более быстрый модный и молодежный способ, или использовать утилиты для меж-сессионого сохранения информация, которые будут видны и на сервере, вроде `cookie`. Первое конечно лучше.